# How to have more control of the icons displayed on the starting screen

Tags: windows-10

Without any apparent reason, the dropbox icon changed to a metro-like icon.

[image]

How can I choose which icons should be displayed here?

Should I use a third-party software?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change those things. This settings are depend upon the developer of the app. And third party software can't do anything with that.